# java Manifest Main-class in contained jar library

Tags: java, manifest

I have a problem with creating executable `jar` with `java -jar myApp.jar` command.

Is it possible to make an executable `jar` where main class is located in one of the libraries in lib folder within `myApp.jar` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make an executable jar where main class is located in one of the libraries in lib folder within myApp.jar file?

No.

The main class needs to be loadable by the standard `JarClassLoader`.  That classloader provides for *external* jars to be enrolled in the classpath via a `Class-Path` entry in the jar's manifest file, but as [the Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) puts it:

> **Note:** The `Class-Path` header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over Internet protocols. ***To load classes in JAR files within a JAR file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those classes.*** For example, if `MyJar.jar` contains another JAR file called `MyUtils.jar`, you cannot use the `Class-Path` header in `MyJar.jar`'s manifest to load classes in `MyUtils.jar` into the class path.

(Emphasis added.)  Since you need custom code to load classes from jars contained within your jar, and you need to load the main class in order to invoke any such code, the main class itself cannot be loaded from an internal jar.

Conceivably, however, you could create a small wrapper class that can be loaded directly, and whose sole purpose is to set up the needed custom classloader and bootstrap the real main class.